# Folder permissions - unable to change owner to domain admins

Tags: windows

I am having issues changing the owner of a folder from my domain admin account to a domain admin security group on a SMB. The error is failed to enumerate and access is denied. I tried disabling inheritance; however I have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried taking ownership?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use the subinacl utility. Here's a sample:

Back up Permissions:

```
subinacl /noverbose /nostatistic /outputlog=C:\temp\SalesAndCustomerServicePermissions.log /subdirectories "E:\UserFiles\Sales & Customer Service\*.*" /display
```

Change Owner on Root Folder:

```
subinacl /errorlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_errorlog1.txt" /outputlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_outputlog1.txt" /file "E:\UserFiles\Sales & Customer Service" /setowner=domain\administrator
```

Change Owner on Subfolders and Files:

```
subinacl /errorlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_errorlog2.txt" /outputlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_outputlog2.txt" /subdirectories "E:\UserFiles\Sales & Customer Service\*.*" /setowner=domain\administrator
```

Grant Permission (Full Control) on on Root Folder:

```
subinacl /errorlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_errorlog3.txt" /outputlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_outputlog3.txt" /file "E:\UserFiles\Sales & Customer Service" /grant=domain\administrator=F
```

Grant Permission (Full Control) on on Subfolders and Files:

```
subinacl /errorlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_errorlog4.txt" /outputlog="c:\temp\SalesAndCustomerService_outputlog4.txt" /subdirectories "E:\UserFiles\Sales & Customer Service\*.*" /grant=domain\administrator=F
```

Restore Permissions:

```
subinacl /nostatistic /playfile C:\temp\LogFileName.log
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51625.subinacl-a-complete-solution-to-configure-security-permission.aspx